# Handle redirection and cookies in PHP and cURL to run curl -b -c -d -Lvk in php

Tags: php, rest, curl, cookies

I am trying to call a Rest API using PHP and cURL. Due to Firewall(F5) restriction, the endpoint URL is redirecting to "my.policy", sets a few cookies and again redirecting it back to the desired endpoint URL.

[image]

To manage this redirection and setting cookie, I found that `curl -b cookie.txt -c cookie.txt -d cookie.txt -Lvk https://myendpointurl` this command helps to store and set the cookies automatically in the next redirection and it is working well as expected.

But how to achieve this in PHP?

I tried to set COOKIEJAR and COOKIEFILE file and also set the FOLLOWLOCATION to true, but no luck.

```
curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, CURL_REDIR_POST_301);
curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) .'/cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) .'/cookies.txt');
```

How to execute the above curl command in PHP and cURL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that to store and call the cookies over HTTPS, only `curl -b cookie.txt -c cookie.txt -Lvk https://myendpointurl` is enough, `-d` is not needed.

To achieve that, what code I had posted in the question is enough except the change in the `CURLOPT_POSTREDIR`. I changed it from  `CURL_REDIR_POST_301` to `CURL_REDIR_POST_ALL` which means it uses the `POST` method in all the redirected URLs.

I am posting this as an answer that might help someone who comes across the same situation.